# Ubuntu 18.04 GRUB menu is not popping out at startup

Tags: boot, grub2

I have an issue that my GRUB is not popping out during the startup

[image]

however if the is "pink" background comes out, and if I immediately press <kbd>ESC</kbd> it can appear normally

[image]

I also need to add that even though the GRUB doesn't pop out, my PC can boot normally, but it's just annoying...

Comment: this is not a problem.. it is the common behavior when there is only one OS (Ubuntu).. installed.. if there are multiple  OS'es (Ubuntu+any other OS), then GRUB will show automatically.. still if you want to see GRUB on every boot at present situation..follow below link..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/16049/739431

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I did uninstall Windows 10 duo boot recently and the reason why I ask is that after deleting and resetting grub, the startup menu pop out sometimes yes, sometimes no, say every 20 times, maybe 1 or 2 it pops out, that's why I ask, but since you say it's normally since there is only one boot system, so I can ignore it. Thanks again!